# Python restarting windows services

Tags: python

Quick question:

I have a python script that will restart a windows service:

```
import os 

import win32serviceutil

serviceName = "Apple Mobile Device"


win32serviceutil.StopService(serviceName)
```

I need to add several other services.

How would I do that?

Thx

Comment: Place all of the services in a list, iterate over the list with a for loop.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to manually enter them each time do something like this:

```
import os 
import win32serviceutil

stopping = 1
while stopping == 1:
    service_name = raw_input('enter the name of the service[s] you would like to stop\nor enter done or exit to exit\n: ')
    if service_name.lower() == 'done' or 'exit':
        stopping = 2
    else:
        try:
            win32serviceutil.StopService(service_name)
            print '{} stopped'.format(service_name)
        except:
            print 'could not stop service {}'.format(service_name)
```

elif you want to do it automagically every time you run the function do something more like *paidhima*:

```
import wmi
import os 
import win32serviceutil



service_name = ['this is service one  :)'
                ,'service 2'
                ,'service 1 million'
                ]
for s in service_name:
    win32serviceutil.StopService(s)
```

else you could list all the services and crash your machine by shutting them all down :)

Comment: In the 2nd example `win32serviceutil.StopService(service_name)`, 'service_name' should be replaced with 's' the current value, rather than the list.

Comment: @Devasish, you will need the `win32all` package.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Where can I download these and how can I use them?